# Showing images on my website from server in php

Tags: php, mysql, image

I'm trying to show some images on a website that I'm building. I have uploaded all the images to my server and have created a database using phpmyadmin in which I list all the path/file names for each image.

This is the code I have tried so far:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Image,Product,Prijs,Description FROM Products order by     Product ASC LIMIT 0, 5"); 
echo '<table border="1px solid black" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:47px"><tbody>'; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{  
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td rowspan='2' width= '200'>" . <'img src=$row['Image']'> . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td><b>" . $row['Product'] . "</b></td>"; 
    echo "</tr>"; 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "&nbsp;<i>Price: &euro;&nbsp;" . $row['Price'] . "</i><br/> <br/></td>"; 
    echo "</tr>"; 

}
```

Now it shows the product name, price, description, but no image.
I'm pretty new to this so I was hoping someone here could help me out :)
Any suggestions?

Comment: Check your quotes in the `img`-line...

Comment: What HTML is it outputting? What HTML did you expect? Does your browser's developer tools' Net tab show it requesting an image? Is the URL it is requesting correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error here:

`echo "<td rowspan='2' width= '200'>" . <'img src=$row['Image']'> . "</td>";`

Should be

`echo "<td rowspan='2' width= '200'><'img src='" . $row['Image'] . "'></td>";`

Needed to close the quotes before declaring the variable. Or:

`echo "<td rowspan='2' width= '200'><'img src='$row['Image']'></td>";`

don't close them. Variables can be used in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $row['Image'] is rendered as html. It should be:

```
echo "<td rowspan='2' width= '200'><img src='" . $row['Image'] . "'></td>";
```

So the codes ends like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Image,Product,Prijs,Description FROM Products order by         Product ASC LIMIT 0, 5"); 
echo '<table border="1px solid black" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:47px"><tbody>'; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{  
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td rowspan='2' width= '200'><img src='" . $row['Image'] . "'></td>"; 
    echo "<td><b>" . $row['Product'] . "</b></td>"; 
    echo "</tr>"; 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "&nbsp;<i>Price: &euro;&nbsp;" . $row['Price'] . "</i><br/> <br/></td>"; 
    echo "</tr>"; 
}
```